# $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't a number field for SAGE

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, sagemath

This is more a question about the weird behavior of SAGE:

```
sage: K.<a> = NumberField(x^3-5)
sage: O_K = K.ring_of_integers()
sage: I_K = O_K.fractional_ideal(3/7)
sage: I_K
Fractional ideal (3/7)
```

But SAGE insists that for `QQ` (which is the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$) there are no fractional ideals:

```
sage: reset()
sage: O_K = QQ.ring_of_integers()
sage: I_K = O_K.fractional_ideal(3/7)
AttributeError: 'sage.rings.integer_ring.IntegerRing_class' object has
no attribute 'fractional_ideal'
```

Comment: When I ask sage to `print type(O_K)` in the first example, it tells me `<class 'sage.rings.number_field.order.AbsoluteOrder_with_category'>`, but in the second example, it tells me `<type 'sage.rings.integer_ring.IntegerRing_class'>`

Comment: @pjs36: What can I do so that `O_K` (which is the same as `ZZ`) is seen as `'sage.rings.number_field.order.AbsoluteOrder_with_category'`?

Comment: Now that I don't know. You can try typing `O_K.` then hit tab, to see what built-in functions exist. I see some `coerce` stuff, but I've never played with it myself. I'm not a CA guy, but here's some [documentation](http://www.sagemath.org/search.html?search=integerring) that could help.

Comment: Related: http://ask.sagemath.org/question/26914/fractional-ideals-for-mathbbz/

Comment: @kcrisman: So I should use the workaround, like `CyclotomicField(1)` instead of `QQ`... ok, this *seems* to work so far...

Comment: See a workaround on [this sage-support discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sage-support/51EZ5obdB1s/discussion).